# how to make triple foreach faster

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I want to get the average of funding for every student in each week with each gender and each replicate.

The following code works at a very slow pace, processing the data would take more than a month.

**How can I make it faster?**

I tried to make an array before the query but failed.

```
$link = new mysqli('localhost','root','','table1');
if ($link->connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $link->connect_errno . ") " . $link->connect_error;
}
$week = [1,3,6,8,11,14,16,19,21,22,26,28,33,35,37,47,55,65,67,70,77,87,89,99,101,122];
$gender = ['M','F'];
$replicate = [1,2,3];
$sum = [];
$relative = [];
foreach ($week as $w) {
  foreach ($gender as $g) {
    foreach ($replicate as $r) {
      sth = $link->query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE week ='".$w."' AND gender ='".$g."' AND replicate ='".$r."'");
      $sum=0;
      while ($row=$sth->fetch_assoc()){
        $sum=$sum+$row['value'];
      }
      unset($sql);
      $sql = array();
      unset($sth);
      $sth1 = $link->query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE week ='".$w."' AND gender ='".$g."' AND replicate ='".$r."'");
      while ($row1=$sth1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $relative=$row1['value']/$sum;
        $query = "UPDATE table1 SET relative = ".$relative." WHERE week =".$w." AND gender ='".$t."' AND replicate =".$r." AND name=".$row1['name']."";
      }
      $link->query($query);
      echo $query;  
    }
  }
} 
mysqli_close ($link);
```

Comment: MySQL has some cool features such as 'sum' and 'group by' you should try them!

Comment: what is the second while supposed to do, if you do not execute it each time with different parameters? `$query = "UPDATE [...]"` will not execute anything, updating only once, *after* your while, when you `$link->query()`

Answer (score 1):

You can make the use of "IN()" clause in SQL like following.

```
$week = [1,3,6,8,11,14,16,19,21,22,26,28,33,35,37,47,55,65,67,70,77,87,89,99,101,122];
$gender = ['M','F'];
$replicate = [1,2,3];

$weeks = implode(',',$week);
$genders = implode(',',$gender);
$replicates = implode(',',$replicate);

 $sth = $link->query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE week IN ($weeks) AND gender IN ($genders) AND replicate IN ($replicates)");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $week, $gender, and $replicate are just a selection of every type of item. If it is actually a filter, you can use an `IN` clause as described by the other answer.

Use the AVG (average) function in a joined update query to update the whole table.

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT AVG(value) AS avg, week, gender, replicate 
  FROM table1 GROUP BY week, gender, replicate
) AS sq
SET t1.relative = sq.avg 
WHERE t1.week = sq.week AND t1.gender = sq.gender
AND t1.replicate = sq.replicate
```

The average is acquired in a sub-query and then is used to populate the table by joining with an update.

In other words:

First, a query is made on the whole table with GROUP BY and AVG, what this does is it merges all values into an average where week, gender, and replicate are the same. It also selects those values so it can match them in the upper query.

The update statement uses the result set from the sub-query, and copies the `avg` result into the `relative` column (as desired by your code) where the week, gender, and replicate match the values selected in the sub-query.

---

EDIT:

Taking a second look, it appears you want something more like this in the query:

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS sum, week, gender, replicate -- (instead of AVG)
...
SET t1.relative = t1.value/sq.sum -- set to their value divided by sum
```